# Preventing a new instance of a program to open when calling it

Tags: linux, bash, memory, buffer

My problem is with FBI (frame buffer image viewer) for Linux, but my question and any answers are perhaps applicable to more than only that program. I don't know. Anyway…

While things are loading on my Raspberry Pi, I display a "Loading screen" through HDMI using FBI. The command in my Bash script is:

```
/usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash/splashscreen.png
```

After a couple of days, I notice that I get an "Out of memory" error instead of the splash screens. It turns out every time a splash screen was displayed, a new instance of FBI was loaded. So there were 50 frame buffer image viewers open causing the memory error, I guess.

Is there any way of making sure a new instance of a program isn't opened when I call for it, or will I have to do something like:

```
pkill fbi
/usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash/splashscreen.png
```

Answer (score 0):

use pgrep to find such processes:

```
if pgrep fbi; then
    echo "already running"
else
    /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash/splashscreen.png
fi
```

or, more quietly

```
pgrep fbi || /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash/splashscreen.png
```

You can use `pkill -0` in place of `pgrep`

Comment: Well, I need to open a new picture in FBI. So using your example won't help.